# Как обрабатывать ботом сообщения -Telegram Bot Api C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

```
 private static async void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
    {}
```

Как обрабатывать ботом сообщения, которые будут приходить, только тогдда, когда я запущу программу? 
Сейчас у меня так как на скрине, и когда я запускаю, то он обрабатывает все новые, которые были до того, как запустился.

Comment: Скрин не прикрепился.

Comment: Пока сообщение не обработано оно не помечается обработанным, соответственно бот будет их получать